# Library not found for -lFirebaseCore

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native

This might be a duplicate but the other threads solutions have not worked.

I have taken over a react-native app and am able to build the app for android on windows but the iOS version has this issue of firebasecore not found.

The reason firebase is now appearing twice is because i followed a guide how to deintegrate pods and reinstall and it duped them.

[image]

When I click the firebasecore file i can check the path its looking in
[image]

It doesnt exist in there.

I have tried to deintegrate the pods and reinstall, update them too.
Open the project using the workspace file.
Delete and clone the repo again to start fresh.

Most of the other solutions too, yet nothing works.

If any other information is needed I can try to provide it!
Thank you for reading!